# Input type range Firefox (bug)

Tags: firefox, input, range

Will there be a vertical implementation of input type range in Firefox? Does anybody know the status of this ussue?

Answer (score 1):

The native implementation of input type range does support rotating the slider. This will hopefully ship with Firefox 22 (now in Nightly). You can drag it up/down with the mouse or use the up/down arrow keys.

Using a Nightly build, have a look at http://jsbin.com/ihifev/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type='range']{        
    width:20px;
    height:140px;
    border:2px solid blue;
    display:block;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */        
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    z-index: 0; 
}
```

Just rotate as you want.

Comment: You can rotate it but the event still tracks horizontal movement.

Answer (score -1):

mozilla does not support range input you can use http://frankyan.com/labs/html5slider/[htnl5.js](http://frankyan.com/labs/html5slider/). It Work in all major browsers.

Comment: I know that I am looking for a vertical implementation which this sollution doesn't have!